# How can I use PySide to quickly resize a PNG?

Tags: python, image, qt, user-interface, pyside

I'm trying to make a small function that will take a thumbnail that has been rendered at twice the required size and resize it with anti-aliasing so that the result is a nice smooth thumbnail.

This is what I've got so far:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

def resizeImage(image, outSize):
    bitmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image)
    bitmap.scaled(QtCore.QSize(outSize, outSize),aspectMode=QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,     mode=QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation) # original is larger than this

    print bitmap.size()
    file = QtCore.QFile(image)
    file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    bitmap.save(file)
    file.close()

resizeImage("image.png", outSize = 256)
```

The problem is the size of the pixmap doesn't seem to change when I call bitmap.scaled - am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used PySide before, but does .scaled do an in-place substitution.  The documentation seems to suggest that it returns a new QPixmap, which your code is not saving.

Maybe this would help:

```
bitmap=bitmap.scaled(QtCore.QSize(outSize, outSize),aspectMode=QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,     mode=QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
```

Comment: That's fixed it! I should have spotted that sooner :D thank you for your help